# Meteor JSON(EJSON) Response parsing difficulties

Tags: json, meteor

I am a newcomer to Meteor and am struggling to convert an external service response format as JSON to a 'parseable' format

Code on server side:

```
if(result){
   console.log("fred" + result);
   console.log(EJSON.stringify(result, {indent: true}));
   var myObj = result;
   console.log(myObj.count);
}
```

The first log statment (server-side) shows that it is an object
The second shows that data has been validly return (via callback)
The third shows undefined as unsuccessful attempt to parse as array.

Then the documentation loses me on how I can query the response for specific elements.  Am I forced to parse client side?

Comment: What are you trying to print in the third `console.log`? `count` is not a property of a JavaScript array or object.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the console output?

Comment: Also do `console.log(typeof(myObj));`

Comment: I20150909-08:40:12.950(-4)?         "u_combine_brk": "3130",
I20150909-08:40:12.950(-4)?         "u_combine_code": "5",
I20150909-08:40:12.950(-4)?         "u_broker_scorecard": "",
I20150909-08:40:12.951(-4)?         "u_broker_segment": "",
I20150909-08:40:12.951(-4)?         "u_broker_applies_to_system_inq": "true"
I20150909-08:40:12.951(-4)?       }
I20150909-08:40:12.951(-4)?     ]
I20150909-08:40:12.952(-4)?   }
I20150909-08:40:12.952(-4)? }
I20150909-08:40:13.004(-4)? object
I20150909-08:40:13.004(-4)? undefined

Comment: You see the tail end of stringify, followed by the result of the typeOf returning object, followed by previous irrelevant count @MichelFloyd,

Comment: It doesn't seem your external service is returning you json.